# Combine Consumers with different arguments or different arguments number

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

Let's say, our method receives **input** String and returns some List **output**. This output is the result of some number of generators, some of which depend on input and some of them not - they just add predefined values. 
I want to implement these generators like a list of some function interfaces (Consumer for example), then combine them into one Consumer and just apply it to the input String.

So, I will able to change small generators easy and independently. But the problem is that not all my generators need **input** String as a parameter and I just pass this parameter there for only one reason - have an ability to combine such Consumers with others.

```
public class ConsumersTest {

private static <T, U> BiConsumer<T, U> combine(List<BiConsumer<T, U>> consumers) {
    return consumers.stream().reduce((arg1, arg2) -> {}, BiConsumer::andThen);
}

List<String> generate(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    combine(getGenerators()).accept(input, output);
    return output;
}

private List<BiConsumer<String, List<String>>> getGenerators() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            this::addFirstDependent,
            this::addSecondIndependent
    );
}

private void addFirstDependent(String input, List<String> output) {
    if (input.contains("some string")) {
        output.add("First-Dependent");
    }
}

private void addSecondIndependent(String input, List<String> output) {
    output.add("Predefined Output");
}}
```

Is it possible to combine different consumers under one umbrella and apply them in one place? Or this is a bad idea and not the right way to do such things?

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or not I can't say.  But it seems you want to be able to categorize your consumers based on argument numbers and type and then feed those consumers correctly.  For the simple case you describe above, you could possiblyhave two lists to be built, one for two argument dependent consumer and one for single argument independent.  Then evaluate them accordingly and combine the ultimate result.

Comment: Yes, I thought about such a solution, but another problem - I need these consumers to be applied in the strict order, like FirstDependent -> SecondIndependent - > ThirdIndependent -> FourthDeendent and so on.

Comment: well, it seems I have faced the same issue before, what I did instead of passing that `String` (in my case I had more than a single argument), is build a `Context`... for `Consumer<Context>` that would need some arguments, I would build that with `Consumer.withAge(12).withName("Eugene")` and so on, for the other type `Consumer.empty()` where all `getters` for such a consumer would throw an Exception... it probably only hides the problem away, but at least someone reading and implementing the code will understand what is going on.

Comment: It looks questionable to receive a `List` as parameter when every “consumer” actually produces a single (optional) value, so it’s either, a supplier or function. Further, going to the whole `combine(getGenerators())` operation, every time, `generate(String input)` is called, is a waste of resources.

Comment: Eugene, yeah, I also have tried this approach. But it's nothing except hiding unused argument. For now, I'm looking for some better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an unusual pattern to have a common interface in a modular software and *adapters*, to make particular implementations fit. E.g.

```
public class ConsumersTest {

    List<String> generate(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        generators.accept(input, output);
        return output;
    }

    private static <T, U> BiConsumer<T, U> ignoreFirstArg(Consumer<U> consumer) {
        return (t, u) -> consumer.accept(u);
    }

    private final BiConsumer<String, List<String>> generators =
        Stream.<BiConsumer<String, List<String>>>of(
                this::addFirstDependent,
                ignoreFirstArg(this::addSecondIndependent)
        ).reduce(BiConsumer::andThen).orElse((arg1, arg2) -> {});

    private void addFirstDependent(String input, List<String> output) {
        if (input.contains("some string")) {
            output.add("First-Dependent");
        }
    }

    private void addSecondIndependent(List<String> output) {
        output.add("Predefined Output");
    }
}
```

So `ignoreFirstArg` is the general adapter for methods not having that first parameter. There can be an arbitrary number of adapter methods. But note that if an adapter is very specific and thus, only use a single time, it’s also possible to write a lambda expression instead of a method reference, right in the combining code. Note that I changed that code, to not get repeatedly evaluated for every `generate(String input)` call, as otherwise, there would be no point in combining them when you don’t reuse the combined function, as you could also use

```
List<String> generate(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    Stream.<BiConsumer<String, List<String>>>of(
            this::addFirstDependent,
            ignoreFirstArg(this::addSecondIndependent)
    ).forEach(g -> g.accept(input, output));
    return output;
}
```

or even simpler

```
List<String> generate(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

    this.addFirstDependent(input, output);
    this.addSecondIndependent(output);

    return output;
}
```

which is not worse to maintain than the functional code, as still, every generator consists of a single line.

Comment: neat idea about the adapter!

Comment: Thanks. Very good answer, and thank you for pointing to the repeated evaluation. Actually, I have already solved this problem in a similar way, but using only Consumer instead of BiConsumer and Consumers. So, I add dependent 
 consumer to the list as a result of another method like addFirstDependentGenerator(String input). So, I'm not ignoring unused parameter, but use it only in that generators where it needed. But, yeah, now for generating a whole list I will need to pass input argument. So, I think, I should use your option to avoid creating a list every time.